# How do I train a randomly initialised embedding layer?

Tags: tensorflow, random, embedding

I am making an embedding layer with randomly initialized embeddings. 
I proceeded this way

```
import tensorflow as tf

vocab_size = 10
embed_dim = 4

# input tokens
mapping_strings = tf.constant(["hello", "lake", "palmer"])

table = tf.contrib.lookup.string_to_index_table_from_tensor(mapping=mapping_strings, 
                                                            num_oov_buckets=1,
                                                            default_value=-1)

# ids for each token
ids = table.lookup(mapping_strings)

embedding_matrix = tf.random_normal(name="embedding_matrix", dtype=tf.float32, 
                                    shape=[vocab_size, embed_dim])

# embedding for each id
embedded_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, ids)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    table.init.run()
    print(sess.run(embedded_inputs))
```

This works and gives me the expected output, but I want these randomly initialized embeddings to be trained later. Where are the weights and biases set? How will backpropagation be performed in order for the embeddings to be learned? Also, is `tf.random_normal` giving me a random variable for the `embedding_matrix` or should I use `tf.Variable`?

Answer (score 0):

As you indicate, in order to train the embeddings you will want to specify them as a `tf.Variable`. You can pass your `tf.random_normal` tensor to the `initializer` argument when creating it.

In order to actually use them in a model, you can use `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` to do lookups for your input data (which should be integers). See also the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#Embeddings).